# Custom control like pivot with more than 50 items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, slideshow

I need to make an item transition like pivot control, but my problem is that pivot control loads all the elements from its binding and it has a loop effect(from the last element navigates to the first and viceversa). Things I tried:

- I tried to make an implementation where I just have 3 pivot items and I change the content of them according to the elements i want to show. The problem that i have there is that I need to change the its ItemTemplate from source, because some of my items are not always the same and I was not able to correctly change the SelectedIndex to navigate across the items.
- I tried to implement my own transitions (swiping an element and loading an usercontrol inside), but the results are not very good, there is a delay till it finish loading all the stuff.

Here is a code sample of how I'm trying to change the current ítem.

```
private void PivotControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((CurrentItem == ListaElem.Count - 1) && (LastPos == 0))
    {
        PivotControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        CurrentItem = 0;
    }
}
```

The control that I want to replicate is Android v4 FragmentManager.

Updated:

[image]

I need a control to be able to navigate throw items and if I'm on item 1, the item 0 and item 2 are preloaded, if I move to item 2, the item 0 should be unloaded for avoid memory problems (each pivot could have 1 or more images) and it preloads the item 3

Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: A fragment sounds a lot like a `UserControl` on the phone. I don't follow your question. Do you want an infinite scrolling pivot that wraps around or not?

Comment: Having more than 7-8 pivot items is also not recommended. Maybe you could add an image of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just updated the question with more info

Comment: custom control with a right preloading/caching strategy is your way.